# Data mining from HTML on PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a nice library using jQuery, which runs in the browser and basically fulfills the task of mining arbitrary data from various html pages. I would like to migrate this library to an Apache server running PHP and run it server-side. However, I do not know about reliable browser emulators compatible with PHP. The worst case scenario is to implement the whole thing again in PHP. This solution would involve:

- sending requests
- parsing HTML
- implementing basic functionalities to do the task performed by Javascript/jQuery standards before
- implement the library from scratch for PHP

However, this is only part of the worst case scenario. The other part is that some pages perform further actions on client-side and then send requests to the server. This means that there are some cases when the initial page load does not contain parts of the data.

In my case it would be ideal to have a server-side browser emulator, which could load the pages and accept javascript commands and give back the responses. Are there some technologies in this area, or should I think about implementing everything from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org), this is WebKit engine "in the console" that can be installed on your server. CaperJS (http://casperjs.org/) also may be useful.